# Ultimate Puzzling Challenge: How it starts

Tags: riddle, story

You are Bob. Today you find a letter in the mail. It says:

> You have been chosen to compete in the Ultimate Puzzling Challenge, along with 1,048,575 others. It is a challenge where you will encounter lots of puzzles, and it is very fun! However, you have to answer a riddle before you actually enter the challenge, and only the first 262,144 people get to compete. Turn this letter over to find the riddle. By the way, here's the layout: There are 3 sections: A,B, and C. A is all about maps, B is all about science (including math) and C is about language (e.g. cryptograms). 
>   -  Mr. Riddle Guy

Of course, you read the back, because after all this looks fun!

> I don't have to move in the air or water,
>   I hunt fish and berries.
>   You will find me in Canada
>   My color is sometimes contrary to my name.
>   What am I?

If you finish, you can get into the Ultimate Puzzling Challenge!

Comment: **NOTE** Puzzle A1 is out. http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33343/ultimate-puzzling-challenge-puzzle-a1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a

> Black Bear.

They

> Walk on the ground.
>  Eat fish and berries.
>  Live in Canada.
>  Aren't always black.

And I believe I am confused if this is the whole answer.

Comment: Ok. Not the intended answer, but it makes sense. Try a different species of bear...

Comment: Correct. Puzzle A1 is coming soon...

Comment: The game is literally afoot!

Answer (score 1):

Are you..

> a Brown Bear

I don't move in the air or water

> Land animal

I hunt fish and berries

> As a brown bear does.

You will find me in Canada

> Bears live in Canada.

Colour is sometimes contrary..

> Brown bears are not always brown.

Like Leppy said - I had this answer but I am totally confused if I (we) are missing another whole layer to this.. I was trying to make sense of the binary numbers, letters, the whole deal.

Comment: The correct answer was black bear, both were viable options, and brown was my first guess as well.  On to step A1.

Comment: I missed that comment. Well now it makes sense..