# Ultimate Puzzling Challenge: Puzzle A1

Tags: story, geography

*Note: The story begins [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33336)*

---

You are Bob. You excitedly go to the starting area to start Section A (maps). You are presented with this letter:

> So you finished that one, huh? You are now starting Section A! To begin, I'll give you a relatively simple one...
>  - Mr. Riddle Guy

Here is the puzzle.

> Two capital cities bordering each other far south, Find the distance to the smallest country anywhere.

Comment: "Find the distance to the smallest country." From where?

Comment: If it's from the starting area, where's the starting area?

Comment: @LeppyR64 if you figure it out you'll realize it doesn't matter ;)

Comment: No. I'm going to revise my problem :p

Comment: @ev3commander you cannot change your question because the only valid answer wasn't what you wanted. The answers posted below are the answers to the question you asked.

Comment: Anyway, the answer from beforedoesn't make sense to me, because according to the map I have, Vatican City doesn't have a capital

Comment: A2 is out. http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33417/ultimate-puzzling-challenge-puzzle-a2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two capital cities sharing a border in the south are:

> Kinshasaa, Democratic Republic of Congo and Brazzaville, Republic of Congo

The smallest country anywhere is:

> Vatican City

The distance between the two is:

> 5120 KM

---

Old Answer before the edit:

The distance from the border of the largest country to the smallest country is:

> 0 km.  They share a border.
>
>  Two possible options are:
>       1. Vatican City and Rome, Italy
>       2. Kinshasaa, Democratic Republic of Congo and Brazzaville, Republic of Congo
>
>  The smallest of these is of course Vatican City

Comment: correct. ( New answer)

Answer (score 5):

Taking a bit of a guess at it..

> 2. (kms from Vatican City, Vatican to Rome, Italy.)

Comment: It's not 2KM, it's 0, because one is INSIDE the other.

Comment: I used information from wikipedia actually, stating center of VC is 2km from Center of Rome. I can see your point, but it depends on what you measure the distance from.

Comment: ye that's true, fair enough