# Ultimate Puzzling Challenge: Puzzle A2

Tags: logical-deduction, story, geography

Note: story starts [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/33336)

---

Bob (aka you) happily goes to the challenge organizers, ready to go on. You get a <s>small</s> large note:

> Hi challenger,
> Looks like you're on to puzzle A2! This is a bit harder, but oh well. I'll give you 2 hints. There will be 3 clues and 3 numbers- L1-L3 and N1-N3. L1-L3's answers will be cities. L1/N1 go together, L2/N2, and L3/N3. 
>  - Mr. Riddle Guy

Ok, so obviously, Bob asks for the clues. Here they are:

> L1/N1: The world's only 3rd level enclave./12386.187
> L2/N2: I am the U.S. state capital that you can't drive to/4593.197
> L3/N3:Two sister islands, in different countries, an important line passes through them./6167.350

Hints:

> What was that word again from A1? di-something? Also, SI > Customary.

What place is next?

Comment: I got the places. Does it have to do anything with coordinates?

Comment: If L1 is the place I think you're referring to, it is no longer a 3rd level enclave since August 2015.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The three places are these:

L1

> [Dahala Khagrabari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dahala_Khagrabari)

L2

> [Juneau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juneau,_Alaska)

L3

> [Diomede Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diomede_Islands)

Then

> Drawing a circle with the given radius (in km) around each location, all three circles intersect in **New York City**.